# SELECT IF EXISTS?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I'm an novice programmer and am wondering if there's a way to right the following code in a format that works correctly. (I always seem to screw up syntax.)

```
$query2 = mysql_query("SELECT IF EXISTS EmployeeName, EmployeeNumber, Position,
ManagementTraining1, ManagementTraining2, ManagementTraining3, ManagementTraining4, 
ManagementTraining5, ManagementTraining6, ManagementTraining7 FROM  
managementMeetingAttendance ORDER BY EmployeeNumber") or die(mysql_error());
```

I'm gathering the data from a dynamically created table and wondering if there's something similar to the 'IF EXISTS' statement that can be made for columns that may or may not exist.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: Don't you know your columns?

Comment: Ooh, that's not a normalized database schema.  I'd set fire to that one and start all over again.  "Dynamically created table"?  Sounds like more trouble.

Comment: Look into [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) to organize your data better. Columns should not be dynamic, added and deleted on the fly. That's a major code smell. And if you can't do that, have a fixed set of columns and insert NULLs into the ones with missing data.

Comment: Upvotes for all of you folks. This isn't NoSQL. The schema must be known ahead of time by any applications that use it. That's just a base requirement. I implore everyone who answers to insist that the schema be fixed, rather than give eval or INFORMATION_SCHEMA based answers.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't but you can first query the database for the column names:

```
select column_name from information_schema.columns where table_name=<TABLE>
```

Comment: This is _potentially_ where he's going to have to go, although I'd personally look into other solutions first.  Including better schema design

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a mySQL person, but I'm unsure of the intent of the statement you've written, and depending on your intent, there might well be an effective answer.

You've got:

```
SELECT IF EXISTS EmployeeName, EmployeeNumber, Position,
ManagementTraining1, ManagementTraining2, ManagementTraining3, ManagementTraining4, 
ManagementTraining5, ManagementTraining6, ManagementTraining7 FROM  
managementMeetingAttendance ORDER BY EmployeeNumber
```

Since you have no where clause, you're presumably not looking for a specific record, and the use of "exists" seems you are simply enquiring whether the table managementMeetingAttendance contains at least one record with the result that the column list and order by statement are irrelevant.

```
((SELECT Count(*) FROM managementMeetingAttendance) > 0)
```

evaluates to true if the table contains a row, or false if it doesnt.

If however you need to determine whether the table does or does not contain each of the columns listed, then this is somewhat more complicated

As per the previous answer, you'd need to use information_schema.columns to get the columns existing for the table and then query this data - something like this:

```
IF EXISTS select 1 from (
    SELECT Column_Name FROM information_schema.columns 
    WHERE table_name = 'managementMeetingAttendance' AND column_name = 'EmployeeName'
) eName AND EXISTS select 1 from (
    SELECT Column_Name FROM information_schema.columns 
    WHERE table_name = 'managementMeetingAttendance' AND column_name = 'EmployeeNumber'
) eNum AND EXISTS select 1 from (
    SELECT Column_Name FROM information_schema.columns 
    WHERE table_name = 'managementMeetingAttendance' AND column_name = 'Position'
) ePos AND EXISTS select 1 from (
    SELECT Column_Name FROM information_schema.columns 
    WHERE table_name = 'managementMeetingAttendance' AND column_name 
        = 'ManagementTraining1'
) eTrng1 AND EXISTS select 1 from (
    etc
```